# Loading CSV file with AlaSQL and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, html-input, alasql

I'm building an HTML based app for querying imported CSV file using AlaSQL. I started with [this demo](http://alasql.org/demo/008file/) and tried to implement the same behavior by setting the `onChange` event through JQuery rather than in the tag. I basically follow the same pattern, and naively pass the event forward to the `loadFile` method. Alternatively, I tried just handling the `alasql` request right in the callback.

html:

```
<input id="with-jquery" name="with-jquery" type="file" />
```

javascript:

```
$('#with-jquery').on('change', function(event)
  {
    console.log('in jquery callback');
    filename = $('#with-jquery').val();
    console.log("filename: " + filename);
    alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[event],function(res){
      console.log('in alasql callback');
        data = res;
        console.log(res);
        document.getElementById("jquery-result").textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
      });
    //loadFile(event);
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FOWwVsW7zAUGwv3BDBdN?p=preview

When I try to load the file using the JQuery handler, I get

```
in jquery callback
test.js:7 filename: C:\fakepath\sample.csv
alasql.min.js:13 Uncaught Error: Wrong usage of FILE() function
```

**Here are some questions:**

1. I can't find documentation for what alasql expects in the `[event]` slot.
2. How does the `FROM FILE` method relate to the more specific `FROM CSV` and `FROM XLSX` methods.
3. The [wiki](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Csv) shows using the `FROM CSV` method by supplying a file name. I can't imagine how that would work without supplying the full path to a local file. But you can't get that from the browser.
4. The [wiki](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/promise) also recommends using the ["promise" format](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/promise). How would I implement that here?