# Alasql import from upload button vs file onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, alasql

I am trying to figure out how to import a file into ALASQL from a file input. There is documentation on how to do this but my client wants to have to press a load button vs when choosing the file.

Here is the documentation from ALASQL:

```
<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<p>Select CSV file to read:&lt;/p>
<input id="readfile" type="file" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
<script>
    function loadFile(event) {
        alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[event],function(data){
            // Process data here
        });
     }
</script>
```

https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How%20to%20upload%20form%20for%20txt%20and%20xlsx%20in%20javascript

My client wants something like this:

```
<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<p>Select CSV file to read:&lt;/p>
<input id="readfile" type="file"/>
<button onclick="loadfile()">Load</button>
<script>
    function loadFile() {
        var file=document.getElementById('readfile').files[0]
        alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[file],function(data){
            // Process data here
        });
     }
</script>
```

I have tried various methods to achieve this but nothing has worked so far. Some of the methods I have tried include creating custom jQuery events and the above example.

I have found a SF article that asks something similar but was unanswered.
[Loading CSV file with AlaSQL and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838028/loading-csv-file-with-alasql-and-jquery)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer I came up with is to split the loadfile process into two functions such as this:

```
<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<p>Select CSV file to read:&lt;/p>
<input id="readfile" type="file" onchange="loadfile(event)"/>
<button onclick="loadfile2()">Load</button>
<script>
    var loadFileTempData=[];
    function loadFile() { //load data file into variable
        var file=document.getElementById('readfile').files[0]
        alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[file],function(data){
            loadFileTempData=data;
        });
     }
     function loadFile2(){ //process data from variable
         var data=loadFileTempData;
         loadFileTempData=[];
         // Process data here
     }
</script>
```